# PHP variables in email body

Tags: php, sql, email

I am trying to assign a variable to email body in php but is not working.

```
$refer=$_POST['refer'];
send_mail(  'admin@auto-sal.es',
                    $_POST['email'],
                    'Invitation from ' .$name,
                    'Hi ".$refer."\n\n join me at auto-sal.es and get 1 month free membership');
```

[image]

I've tried using double quotes instead of single quotes but nothing happens any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
"Hi \"$refer\"\n\n join me at auto-sal.es and get 1 month free membership");
```

You are enclosing the string in single quotes. Single quotes work differently from dobule quotes. If you put `"` or a variable inside single quotes they will be interpreted literally, and that's what is happening to you.

You should also take a look at the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) that states:

> Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 3):

Needs to be:

```
'Hi '.$refer.'\n\n
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct string concat is:

```
"Hi ".$refer."\\n\\n join me at auto-sal.es and get 1 month free membership"
```

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes should actually fix the problem. Like this:

```
"Hi $refer,\n\n join me at auto-sal.es and get 1 month free membership");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'Hi '.$refer.'\n\n join me at auto-sal.es and get 1 month free membership')
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you Try doing this in the code?

```
'.$refer.'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'Hi' . $refer . "\n\n" . ' join me at auto-sal.es and get 1 month free membership.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, your outer single quotes mean that everything within them apart from other single quotes will be interpreted as plain characters, so the double quotes you have around .$refer., along with .$refer. itself, are passed through just as they are. All the answers above solve the problem in different ways, but essentially they all make sure your $refer variable is interpreted as a variable to be interpolated into the string, rather than a dollar sign next to a word. Any of the answers will suit your purposes admirably.